# How to integrate cordova plugin with MobileFirst Application?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I am newbie to MobileFirst (Worklight) and i don't know how to integrate cordova plugin with MobileFirst Application. Please help me to integrate cordova plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the ibm documentation here you have to add your plugin in config.xml

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/ios-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

Comment: as per your link,this is for MF version 6.3. is this process is same for 7.1 version as i'm using 7.1 MF version.

Comment: Yes. the process of adding to config.xml didn't change change.